# Request failed: unauthorized (401) IOS LinkedinAPI

Tags: ios, linkedin-api

I've looked at similar questions but none seem to solve this problem. I use the query below access information from Linkedin. I know the URL is correct because I've tested it on apigee.com but I keep getting the same error. This is after the user has logged in and I've been authorized. What am I doing wrong?

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"LinkedInUser"];
[query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:user];
[query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *linkedInResults,     NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {

        [PFLinkedInUtils.linkedInHttpClient GET:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(first-name)?oauth2_access_token=%@&format=json", linkedInResults[@"accessToken"]] parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id result) {

            NSLog(@"Response JSON: %@", result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You say you are logged in? That means the server would have given you an authentication key that you have to supply in all following requests. But you didn't, which is why you get an error.

Look carefully at the response that you get. A status 401 will always tell you what authentication you have to supply to be allowed in.